# Trying to "gem install rails" - but it does absolutely nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've never used or touched Ruby/Rails before. I'm installing it for the very first time. I'm using Windows 8.

I'm on Step 4 of InstallFest here:

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows?back=choose_your_operating_system

I've typed "gem install rails" and hit Enter into the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails.

Nothing happens though. It stays at the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17grK.png

I've waited for quite some time and it appears to just stay at the screen when I hit Enter. I've tried using variations like "gem install rails -V" and "gem install -V rails" and the same thing happens.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Rails is a nightmare on Windows, you're on like step 3 out of 1000 and once you're past this hurdle there are another 300 of those 1000 steps that'll also be a nightmare. My recommendation is to use vagrant or docker or something to run a Linux VM for your Rails development.

Comment: Why is Mac better for Ruby/Rails development? What makes it better than Windows?

Comment: It's because since Mac OS X, the Mac sits atop a GNU/UNIX-like operating system which means that all the standard UNIX-y tools work. Windows does not, and has its own command interpreter (cmd.exe) which is incompatible with UNIX tools. This means that Windows users either use layers like cygwin or MinGW and deal with the complexity and package dependencies of those, or they spend their lives hunting for native Win32 versions of all the compiled tools and dealing with the special setups and issues of those.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this myself.

Turns out my firewall was blocking the installation. So I changed my firewall settings.

But then there was another issue. I got the following error after hitting "gem install rails":

ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Did some Googling, and entered this "gem source -a http://rubygems.org/". Then I tried installing Rails again- and voila, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try `gem install rails -v 4.1.8` if you want to specify the version, if not just run `gem install rails`

Disclaimer: I have never run rails on Windows.

Comment: Would you happen to know why it isn't doing anything I when I Enter that?

Comment: you entered `gem install -V rails` did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes. The same thing happens.

Comment: if you ever considered switching to Apple, now would be a good time!